# Error in php script when hosted in the remote server only

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have an android app with php backend, the problem is one of the php scripts works perfectly on the local server while when online it does not and produce the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/malblbic/public_html/webservice/profile.php on line 23

Here is my php code.

```
<?php

/*
Our "config.inc.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to add a new user to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.inc.php");


//initial query
$username = $_POST['username'];
    $query = "Select * FROM users;

//execute query
try {
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response[‘success’] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();

        $post["picture"] = $row["picture"];
        $post["username"] = $row["username"];

        $post["points"] = $row["points"];


        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Users Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

?>
```

Comment: Besides the smart/curly quotes in `[‘success’]` (which has already been mentioned below, you're missing a `"` in `$query = "Select * FROM users;` Notice syntax highlighting? - Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 1):

Change backticks to regular quotes

```
$response[‘success’] = 0;
```

To

```
$response['success'] = 0;
```

Comment: Further I suggest that when php is reporting an error on a particular line, inspect that line carefully. @FuzzyTree spotted the obvious problem here and if you looked at line 23 you probably would have noticed the issue.